# Capybara - if, else

Tags: capybara

if I write in capybara the following code

```
if find("tr", :text => "No data available in table")
  ...function... 
end
```

it doesn't work, but if I write

```
if find("tr", :text => "No data available in table") do
  ...function... 
end
```

it works.

In the same way, if I write

```
if find("tr", :text => "No data available in table")
  ...function... 
else
  ...function...
end
```

the test doesn't work and it gives me an alert that says: "syntax error, unexpected keyword_end". How do I fix the problem?

Comment: Capybara's `find` doesn't use any block passed to it, so your first statement is strange. The code that you show in your second statement is valid. Better show more context.

Comment: Actually it was my mistake as I really had probably some "end" interfering somewhere. Now I can say that the first statement is the one that works to me, and the third one consequently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#find` raises an exception if it doesn't locate an element, so using it in an if/else doesn't make any sense - what you want is `has_css?` which does return a Boolean

```
if has_css?("tr", text: "whatever")
  ......
else
   .....
end
```

Note: you can pass a wait: option to `has_css?` if you want to shorten (or lengthen) the time `has_css?` Will wait for the element to appear - so `wait: 0` if you know the page is already fully loaded and just want an immediate check